# (Drupal 7) How do I modify an existing term reference of a select list?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

This is a question on how Drupal 7 works. I don't have Drupal experience and would like to fix this small issue in the short term until I can learn the framework.

I have a list of years (2006 - 2020) in a select list. I would like to add more years to that select list. The select list is a term reference field used to group content.

1. Is the solution to go into some php files and add years to the variable holding it?
2. Are term fields a column in a database, thus requiring database manipulation as well?

Comment: Why doesn't add term into term vocabulary directly ?

Comment: @Fky That's the answer! I was given normal user credentials but now logged in as an admin so I can see that option (and more). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Drupal is done through the dashboard which is available when signed in as an **administrator**.

To add a term to a taxonomy list you can do the following:

> `Structure`
>
> > `Taxonomy`
> >
> > > `(vocabulary name)`
> > >
> > > > `Add term`